# What is the [exposed] tag for, and should we have an [xposed] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Due to the lack of a tag wiki, it's unclear what the [exposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exposed) tag is for.

- Questions about Drupal or Drupal's exposed filter may get this tag although a separate [drupal-exposed-filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-exposed-filter) tag already exists.
- Questions about Android's [Xposed framework](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed) may also get this tag. Should we have a separate [xposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xposed) or [xposed-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xposed-framework) tag to cover these questions? There aren't many [questions about](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xposed) this framework or its modules (but 88 is more than [drupal-exposed-filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-exposed-filter)'s 56) - it's simply a matter of correct categorization.
- Other questions come from C++ X11, .Net WCF, Java GWT, Rest API, and even PHP/MySQL (simply because the question title has *"password exposed"*).

The most ridiculous example is probably [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9272686/1134080) tagged [exposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exposed) just because the **book title** is *"Programming Interviews Exposed"*.

What should we do?

Comment: Yes, this tag is completely useless, and should be **burninated**.